# Move observations on fawlty dates to the right date in grouped data using R

Tags: r, date, group-by

Some observations in my data are recorded at the wrong date and I would like to correct this.

My data looks like this:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
value <- c(NA,50,NA, 100, NA, NA, 75, NA, 150, NA, NA,80,100,NA)
type <- c("f",NA, "e", "f","e","e", NA, "e", NA, "e", "f", NA, NA, "e")
date <- as.Date(c("2019-01-10","2019-01-15","2019-02-01","2020-01-10","2020-02-10","2020-03-10","2020-03-18","2020-04-15","2020-06-01","2020-06-07","2020-07-01","2020-07-10","2020-11-25","2020-12-01"))
extra <- c(NA,222,NA, 333, NA, NA, 444, NA, 555, NA, NA, 666, 777, NA )                 

df1 <- data.frame(id, value, type, date, extra)
df1

id value type  date        extra
1    NA    f   2019-01-10    NA
1    50 <NA>   2019-01-15   222
1    NA    e   2019-02-01    NA
2   100    f   2020-01-10   333
2    NA    e   2020-02-10    NA
2    NA    e   2020-03-10    NA
2    75 <NA>   2020-03-18   444
2    NA    e   2020-04-15    NA
2   150 <NA>   2020-06-01   555
2    NA    e   2020-06-07    NA
3    NA    f   2020-07-01    NA
3    80 <NA>   2020-07-10   666
3   100 <NA>   2020-11-25   777
3    NA    e   2020-12-01    NA
```

I would like to group my data based on "id".

Then, if "type" is "NA" I would like to  move the observations in "value" and "extra" to the row closest in time (based on "date") that has a valid "group" value.

So, I would like my data to look like this:

```
id <- c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3)
value <- c(50,NA, 100, NA, 75, NA, 150,80,100)
type <- c("f" ,"e", "f","e","e", "e", "e","f","e")
date <- as.Date(c("2019-01-10","2019-02-01","2020-01-10","2020-02-10","2020-03-10","2020-04-15","2020-06-07", "2020-07-01","2020-12-01"))
extra <- c(222,NA, 333,NA, 444, NA, 555, 666, 777)  

df2 <- data.frame(id, value, type, date, extra)

df2

id value type  date       extra
1    50    f   2019-01-10   222
1    NA    e   2019-02-01    NA
2   100    f   2020-01-10   333
2    NA    e   2020-02-10    NA
2    75    e   2020-03-10   444
2    NA    e   2020-04-15    NA
2   150    e   2020-06-07   555
3    80    f   2020-07-01   666
3   100    e   2020-12-01   777
```

Comment: Do you want to remove `NA` values from `type` column ? `df1 %>% filter(!is.na(type))` ?

Comment: Hi! Yes there should be no NAs in the "type" column. But the numerical value in the "value" column that has an NA should be moved to the row with closest date.